# error desinstalar docker

Tags: docker

hago el purge en ubuntu del docker y auto remove pero al momento de el siguiente comando:

```
$sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
```

me tira el error:                                                                                                                                 
**rm: no se puede borrar '/var/lib/docker/aufs': Dispositivo o recurso ocupado**, he buscado diferentes formas pero resulta que no he podido desinstalar completamente docker...
ayuda por favor en este problema

Comment: Puede ser que haya un proceso activo, intenta buscarlo con el comando ps y mirando los nombres, por si tuvieras uno que se llame docker.

Comment: ya lo logre remover, lo  hice purge y todo no tengo nada de docker instalado, pero al hacer **docker -v**, me sigue dando la version de docker

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get purge -y docker-engine
sudo apt-get autoremove -y --purge docker-engine
sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get purge -y docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce
sudo apt-get autoremove -y --purge docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce
```

Hay que seguir la guia de desinstalación de docker en la página oficial de docker, pero si ya lo hiciste por fuera puedes seguir estos comandos.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker

sudo rm /etc/apparmor.d/docker

sudo groupdel docker

sudo rm -fr /var/run/docker.sock
```

Pueden seguir quedando archivos, para buscarlos

```
find / -name '*docker*'
```

Y borrar estos files